# Does redshift serialize write operations?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We are running a 5 dc1.large node cluster and are having issues scaling our data loading.

Each "loader" is a separate process that:
- runs a COPY command from S3 into a staging table 
- then a delete is performed on the live table (to remove the rows that are in the staging table)
- finally the staging data is inserted into the main table

The above is basically the recommended technique in the [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/merge-replacing-existing-rows.html):

An important detail to note is that each loader is operating on separate set of tables (ie there is no lock contention between loaders because they operate on different customer data sets) So loader one will copy into L1_Staging table and ultimately into the L1_main table, loader two will copy into L2_staging and ultimately into L2_main table etc..

What we're noticing is that when we multiple loaders running in parallel the job times increase as if  redshift is serializing all write operations. Again, there is no lock contention.

Why are we seeing this pattern? Does redshift not handle parallel writes well?

Comment: Is it possible that the writes are using the available bandwidth to the storage?  If the query is I/O bound, then additional threads will not run any faster.

Comment: The query is definitely i/o bound, its a large insert followed by a delete followed by another insert. Redshift is a black box so I don't really know how much IO throughput I'm consuming with each query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes redshift does indeed serialize all operations. Everything is queued in their WLM (workload management) queue

Answer (score 1):

You will get better performance if you can [split each load](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-use-multiple-files.html) into a number of files that is a multiple of the nodes (5 in your case). With one file you are limited to the throughput of one node.

It is helpful to use a [manifest file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/best-practices-preventing-load-data-errors.html) with multiple file loads. Also compress your files and enable compression on your table columns. Table compression adds computation but the data can then be moved between nodes more quickly to get were it needs to go (load node isn't the same as at rest node).

Since you're doing a frequent and heavy delete operation you need to schedule [regular `vacuum` operations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_VACUUM_command.html) on the affected tables.

Queries (including copies) can run concurrently but the simultaneous number is limited by resources (default is 5 per node). That can be tweaked a bit. So you should be able to load different tables efficiently. As indicated above the issue probably has more to do with loading single files. Check out the info on [query queues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-defining-query-queues.html).

Here are some [other hints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_loading-data-best-practices.html).